# exhausted memory while allocating

Tags: php, memory, memory-management

**CODE:**

```
if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX))
{
    fwrite($fp, serialize($this->_contents));
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
}
```

**ERROR:**

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 17805286 bytes).....
```

**ERROR LINE:**

```
fwrite($fp, serialize($this->_contents));
```

Any idea how to solve the issue? My site hosted on shared hosting so I have no chance changing memory settings.

Thanks

Comment: What is inside $this->_contents?

Comment: The serialize function can use a lot of memory, if you can try to iterate over the contents of each item of the $this->_contents and sterilize each item one by one, then manually wrap the outside of that string with the final markup for each item. I'd have to go over the details of the serilze function to tell you how to do that directly but it should be pretty easy for you to look that information up yourself.

Comment: `$this->_contents` has about 1.5million records coming from DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely `serialize($this->_contents)` is the problem.
I generally tend to suggest to NOT use serialization to store things in a db or files.

You should split the data inside `_contents` and write them separately.

Answer (score 0):

> *It might not solve your memory issue (as you can not change that you can not change that), but it might allow you more control:*

For either the class of `$this` or `$this->_content`, you could implement the [`Serializeable`](http://php.net/class.serializable) that returns the data in a more memory-optimized way.

If you can really memory optimize it then, you could transparently use it with `serialize`.